# How to remove hdf5 configuration created by Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-2017, hdf5

[image]

According to my screenshot, there is "Headers are 1.10.4, library is 1.10.5". I used conda to install hdf5 1.10.4. However, the library is always linked to version 1.10.5. In fact, "Installation point: C:/Program Files/HDF5" did not exist.

In addition, Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 had been uninstalled.

I spent more than an hour to search for a solution. But nothing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
pip uninstall h5py

pip install h5py
```

You may run `pip uninstall h5py` multiple times if you are not sure if there are multiple versions installed.
IDK why. But it works!